# Itens de array relativas ao adicionar novo item

Tags: javascript, array

Possuo uma `array` que possui 10 itens, por exemplo:

```
var array_exemplo = ["item_1", "item_2", "item_3", "item_4", "item_5", "item_6", "item_7", "item_8", "item_9", "item_10"];
```

E, no meu html, possuo vários botões, com id's, por exemplo:

```
<button id="item_12">12</button>
<button id="item_27">27</button>
<button id="item_54">54</button>
```

Porém, gostaria que, ao clicar em algum botão, adicionasse o id na array no primeiro item, e os outros passarem para o item seguinte, como por exemplo (se eu clicasse no botão com id = item_54):

```
var array_exemplo = ["item_54", "item_1", "item_2", "item_3", "item_4", "item_5", "item_6", "item_7", "item_8", "item_9"];
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o método `unshift` que insere um novo valor no início da lista da `array`:

```
    var array_exemplo = ["item_1", "item_2", "item_3", "item_4", "item_5", "item_6", "item_7", "item_8", "item_9", "item_10"];

    var button = document.getElementById("item_54");

    button.onclick = function(){

        array_exemplo.unshift(this.id);

    }
```

**Caso queira fazer isso no HTML:**

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="item_54" onclick="addId(this.id)">
```

JS

```
    var array_exemplo = ["item_1", "item_2", "item_3", "item_4", "item_5", "item_6", "item_7", "item_8", "item_9", "item_10"];

    function addId(Id){

        array_exemplo.unshift(Id);

    }
```

Comment: Perfeito! Nem imaginava da existência do `unshift`! Muito obrigado!